# an error in Androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SimpleAndroidOCRActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

</manifest>
```

in this code.everything seems to be okey. but I got an error in  "" android:name=".SimpleAndroidOCRActivity" "" in this field. why I got this error .

thank you for your helps....

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `Activity` you're referring to is actually named `SimpleAndroidOCRActivity`?

Comment: That's weird I really don't see what could cause an error. I'll re-check everything but it looks fine for me...
Have you tried rebuilding and cleaning the project?

Comment: I solved this problem . I got this error.because ı did not import my tesseract library.when ı have import this library my problem was solved.thank you for your helps and I am sorry for your time spending...

Comment: You don't have to be sorry !  And I'm glad you figured it out :D